# Fint a asp control on page but returns NULL

Tags: asp.net, controls, httpcontext

,HI,

On my .aspx page i have a dataGrid with id = "dataGrid1", I need to edit that control for on class in the app_code.

This is what i am doing in my class:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is Page)
        {
            Page currentPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            if (currentPage != null)
            {                  
                Control ctrl = FindControlRecursive(currentPage, "dataGrid1");
            }
        }
```

Then i have this recursive function:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id)
        {
            return root;
        }

        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (t != null)
            {
                return t;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But for some reason it doesnt find my control and returns null.

Can any one help???

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already getting instance of the page, try adding public method that will return the Grid, then have such code:

```
Page currentPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
if (currentPage != null)
{     
    DataGrid myGrid = (currentPage as YourClassName).GetGrid();
    ...
}
```

Also, what is the context of your code? When does it get executed?

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but since i am new the asp, can you please give a complete example? Were should i ad the public method?

Comment: Add the public method in the page class that inherit from `Page`.. probably code behind of the `.aspx` also please let us know when the code you posted is being executed.. is it after button click? Inside module?

Comment: If i understand correctly the code is being executed inside module.

Comment: What is YourClassName? i tried the name of my class that all this code is in but that didnt work.

Comment: This is the name of the class inheriting from `Page`

Comment: got it, but since that class is in code behind the .aspx page, and i am trying to use it in a separate class in app_code, it deosnt recognize the class name...

Comment: Sorry.. out if ideas and anyway, good chance it's dead end since inside HttpModule, the page might not be "ready" just yet, which explains why the control is not found. Why not edit the grid in Page_PreRender event?

Comment: Thanks i will have to figure out something else. thanks for your help.